# How to remove a date than is lower than today's date in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, datetime, object

I would like to remove a date from an object than is lower than today's date: e.g. Today is: `2022-08-17` and I got `{ date: "2022-08-15" },` in my array of objects.

```js
let todayDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);

let arr = [
  { date: "2022-08-15" }, // todayDate is 2022-08-17 and this object should be removed
  { date: "2022-08-31" },
  { date: "2022-10-19" },
  { date: "2022-10-27" },
];

// result after filter 

// let arr = [
 // { date: "2022-08-31" },
 // { date: "2022-10-19" },
//  { date: "2022-10-27" },
```

Comment: ok ty for the minuses wo/ explanation :-)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the date with the `Date` constructor, then check whether it is greater than the current date:

```js
let arr = [
  { date: "2022-08-15" },
  { date: "2022-08-31" },
  { date: "2022-10-19" },
  { date: "2022-10-27" },
];

const now = Date.now()
const result = arr.filter(e => new Date(e.date) > now)
console.log(result)
```

Alternatively, you could compare the strings lexographically:

```js
let todayDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);

let arr = [
  { date: "2022-08-15" },
  { date: "2022-08-31" },
  { date: "2022-10-19" },
  { date: "2022-10-27" },
];

const result = arr.filter(e => e.date > todayDate)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Why did you add `now` and what do you think does `todayDate` mean? It's not necessary to convert the date strings. ISO 8601 date strings can be lexicographically compared. Your code also removes today's date, except at 00:00:00.000, so the first code is wrong.

Comment: what if I got an array: `['2022-08-15', '2022-08-31', '2022-09-19', '2022-09-28', '2022-10-19', '2022-10-27']` instead of array of objects? I tried this code and didn't work with just arrays - with array of objects it works. Thank you btw. Sounds like I got to do for loop or forEach method or map? because I now filter through array indexes instead of object props i.e. `arr.filter(e => e.date > todayDate)`

Comment: @xxxbud use `arr.filter(e => e > todayDate)` in that case